# How to use a parameter on the url with react-router-dom and query string and use it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a calendar and a select, when I select the doctor, his planning will be appeared on my calendar.

I used a react-router on my App.js as you see :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import Agenda from './components/Agenda/Agenda';
import Planning from './components/Planning/Planning';
class App extends Component {
  /*---------------------------------------------------- Rendu -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter  basename="/ReactCalendar">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Agenda} />
            <Route exact path="/affichageRDV" component={Planning} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

And on my package.json I have :  `"homepage": "https://prodTest/ReactCalendar"`,
When I build it, and push it on my server and run it on `https://prodTest/ReactCalendar/`

But I want on my App fetch the identifiant_user and let it as the parameter on the url like that `https://dev.alaxione.fr/ReactCalendar/?identifiant_user=2157887

How to send the identifiant_user on my Agenda because it's a parameter to fetch the planning from the backend and use it as a parameter on the url ?

Such as on my Agenda.js I fetched the planning like that:

```
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND+'get_liste_planning/85flna?start='+moment().startOf('isoweek').toJSON()+'&end='+moment().endOf('isoweek').toJSON()+'&identifiant_user=2157887')
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let evts = data.ListeResult;
        for (let i = 0; i < evts.length; i++) {
          evts[i].start = moment(evts[i].start).toDate();
          evts[i].end = moment(evts[i].end).toDate();
          this.state.evtBackend.push(evts[i])
        }                   
        this.setState({
          evtBackend: evts,
          events:  evts
        })
```

How can I fix it  ?

Answer (score 0):

You need this,

```
<Route exact path="/:identifiant_user" component={Agenda} /> //`:identifiant_user` is the param
```

As `identifiant_user` is seems to be static you can maintain in state,

Usage,

```
<Link to={`/identifiant_user=${this.state.identifiant_user}`}>
```

Comment: I want like that `https://dev.alaxione.fr/ReactCalendar/?identifiant_user=2157887`